# Showing the function veing identically zero everyhere according to given constraints

Tags: calculus, functions

*If a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies functional equation  $g(xy) = g(x) + g(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and there is a number $z \neq 1$ such that $g(z) = 0$ then $g(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$.*.

> 1. I have shown that if g(z) = 0 then as $g(z^{any rational power})$ = $zg(z)=0$ , but how can we show that from this that g(x) = 0 for all x belonging to R ?
>    2. And is it possible that there exists function satisfying the above functional equation but its being **not continuous** at some points ?

Comment: You can approximate any $x>0$ as $x\approx z^r$ for $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ (assuming $z>0$ and $z\neq 1$).

Comment: If $f$ is any solution of the Cauchy's equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ then $g(x)=f(\ln x)$ satisfies your functional equation. The are lots of dis-continuous solutions of the Cauchy's equation.

Comment: Understood @KaviRamaMurthy , Michael , how we can say so ? Is there a fact which lead us to believe we can always approximate any such x ? How can we say by raising to a rational power we can always get to the desired x ? Is it by taking a rational number closest to lnx/lnz ? Which might be irrational

Comment: Just solve the equation $x=z^r$ when we do not care if $r$ is rational or not. Or write $z^r = e^{r \log(z)}$.

Comment: Just approximate $\frac {ln \, x } {\ln z  }$ by a rational number $r$.

Comment: Okay so we are saying as the approximation is very close , so we get limf(x) = limit f(2^r) = limit(0) = 0 , the left hand and right hand side of limit we dont need to worry about because its automatically being handled in this case ? From that approximation  @Michael . Yeah that i was thinking Kavi Sir